# Flash plugin not working

Tags: 11.10, flash

I am using 11.10 on an old intel mac. I have trouble viewing flash videos, and even after installing the plugin I cannot see them on either browser (FF/Chrome). On Chrome, it seems the shockwave flash does not exist in "about:plugins". So how can I get it in my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal (Ctrl +Alt + T) and run the command `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`. This will download and install flash. As a temporary solution until you fix the problem if this does not work, you can enable the YouTube HTML5 player by going to www.YouTube.com/html5 and enabling the option. This will allow you to still watch videos without having flash installed.